# How To Access Sub Class Variable From Generic Super Class

Tags: java

I am trying to create a generic method, but it requires data from the sub class. Is there a way to do this, or is there a better implementation?

Example of my situation:

```
public class Super {
    public static Object method() {
        return doSomethingWith(specificToSubClassValue);
    }
}

public class Sub1 extends Super {
    public static String specificToSubClassValue = "123";
}

public class Sub2 extends Super {
    public static String specificToSubClassValue = "456";
}
```

I obviously cannot do this. What is a better approach?

One alternative I can think of is to override the #method method in each sub class, but it will be the same code in each instance so I wanted to throw it in the parent class (and it won't be truly overridden since it is static), but I am not sure how to approach it since it is dependent on the sub class value.

Comment: static methods are not invoked polymorphically. They can't be overridden.

Comment: I know I mentioned that in parenthesis. Part of the reason for this question :) I was looking for a way around it, but can't think of a working solution. I think my implementation is (obviously) poor and wanted to know of a good way around this type of problem or the proper implementation to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an abstract method in `Super`, which will be used to return the value from the implementing classes. Note that this can only be achieved with non-static methods. As per @JB Nizet's comment, static methods cannot be overriden by subclasses. I've removed the static modifier from the code below to shown you how it would work.

```
public class Super {
    public static Object method() {
        return doSomethingWith(specificToSubClassValue);
    }

    protected abstract Object getValue ();
}

public class Sub1 extends Super {
    public static String specificToSubClassValue = "123";

    @Override
    protected Object getValue () {
        return specificToSubClassValue;
    }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super {
    public static String specificToSubClassValue = "456";

    @Override
    protected Object getValue () {
        return specificToSubClassValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: method() is static. It can't call getValue(). (and you forgot to call it anyway).

Comment: @JBNizet True, I failed to see that his methods were static. I'll adjust my answer, thanks ;)

Comment: Let me know when you adjust your answer :)

Comment: @rys I adjusted the explanation, but I did not change the code, because what you wish to achieve is not possible with static methods. I give an example of what could be done with non-static methods, which would be the proper way to solve the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods in Java can't be overwritten, and can't access children-specific information: they know nothing about inheritance.

What you need here is instance method, which you can overwrite. An you also may use generics.

```
public class Super<T> {
    public Object method() {
        final T specificToSubClassValue = getSpecificToSubClassValue();
        if (specificToSubClassValue != null) {
            return specificToSubClassValue.hashCode();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected T getSpecificToSubClassValue() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Sub1 extends Super<String> {
    @Override
    protected String getSpecificToSubClassValue() {
        return "abc";
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Super<Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer getSpecificToSubClassValue() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a solution when `method` is `static`?

Comment: @rys no. Static method belongs *only* to class in which it is declared. It can't have access to current instance, so it can't be used with inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

Well, te whole idea of inheritance is that the superclass should not be able to do that much without the sub-class. Otherwise the whole inheritance would be pointless exercise and spaghetti code. But you are tackling the problem the wrong way. Make sub-class "spill" the data you need (through getter) and use the generic method from superclass on the data in the sub-class.

Also the overriding of super class methods is highly overrated. You should strive for your super method to be as flexible and re-usable as possible, and even then strive rather for overloading, instead of overriding.

You could have:

```
public class Super {
    public Object method(String specificValue) {
        return doSomethingWith(specificToSubClassValue);
    }
```

And then have your sub do this

```
public class Sub1 extends Super {
    public static String specificToSubClassValue = "123";
    Object method(specificToSubClassValue);
}
```

This way you accomplish exactly what you want, operate on the class specific value using the super method.